# Django: AJAX + CSRF POST gives 403

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

I have a simple code where I make a `POST` call to URL in `Django` with CSRF token included. When I paste the `javascript` code in the template within `<script>` tags, it works fine, however as soon as I move the code to a static file, I get HTTP 403 response. This is strange!

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".like-button").click(function(event) {
        $.ajax({
            url: <relative path of URL>,
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{ csrf_token }}",
                // other data items
            },
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {},
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {}
        });
        // other javascript code to toggle like button class
    });
});
```

Here's how I include the static file in `Django` template:

```
{% block javascript %}
{% load static %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'app/app.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

The file is located in static directory:

```
app
├── static
│   └── app
│       └── app.js
```

and static settings are:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

Note, I do not have `STATICFILE_DIRS` in the settings yet. I can verify that the file is being loaded and executed, since `console.log()` statements work perfectly fine. However, I get HTTP 403 request upon `POST`.

Comment: Check the permissions of your static file. Make it weserver readable (666 permission for test)  and try again.

Comment: @Randi: I did `chmod 666` and that doesn't help.

Comment: Then make sure that `STATIC_ROOT` and `STATICFILES_DIRS` are correctly set in your settings.py. And don't forget to run `manage.py collectstatic` command if you are in development. It will also help if you mention the exact error message and your file structure.

Comment: 403 is the error given by csrf as well, django recommends https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/csrf/ to get csrf token via javascript, I'm not sure completely

Comment: @Randi: `manage.py collectstatic` doesn't help either.

Comment: @Mikeec3: I am able to successfully include the CSRF token when the script is pasted in the template itself. It's only when I move the code to the file, I get the error.

Comment: @abhinavkulkarni Please add your settings for these to your question: `STATIC_ROOT` and `STATICFILES_DIRS` .

Comment: Oh I get it, you know django doesn't render static files unless onthe template. Lol forgot to mention that. Unless its <script> {{ context}} </script>

Answer (score 2):

When you use the  tag directly, django processes the templates and replaces `csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{ csrf_token }}"` by the correct token.

Now, when you use a static file, that variable isn't replaced.
In order to add a token you should configure your ajax calls described by django documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax

```
      function getCookie(name) {
        var cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
          var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
          for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
              cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
              break;
            }
          }
        }
        return cookieValue;
      }
      var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
      $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
          xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

From Django documentation:

```
NOTE:
The CSRF token is also present in the DOM, but only if explicitly
included using csrf_token in a template. The cookie contains the
canonical token; the CsrfViewMiddleware will prefer the cookie to the
token in the DOM. Regardless, you’re guaranteed to have the cookie if
the token is present in the DOM, so you should use the cookie!
```

jQuery cookie plugin:

```
var csrftoken = $.cookie('csrftoken');
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/csrf/

Any static file not rendered directly on the template cannot make use of django's templating engine. You need to use the csrf cookie.

Check your javascript during runtime, you'll notice the template variable is an empty string.